# search the string of third column in other column if found paste its adjacent values using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 columns city,area and pincode. notice that most of  the areas are not present in area column and they are present in city column so infornt of city I want to fillup pincodes using area and pincode column

```
City            Area            Pincode 
Mumbai                      
Pune            Bandra E        123456
Bandra(W)       Badalapur       789456
Bandra(E)       
Badlapur        Mumbai          159357
                Pune             411009
```

I want to use city column as a search string as I have already filled NaN values using area and pincode column but there is a city for which I dont see any pincodes in pincode column therefore I want to use city column as search string. can we consider Area and pincode as my master table and with the help of these 2 column fill up missing pincodes of city? Thanks

expected output

City            Area            Pincode 
Mumbai                          159357
Pune            Bandra E        123456
Bandra(W)       Badalapur       789456
Bandra(E)                       123456
Badlapur        Mumbai          159357
                Pune             411009

Comment: From sample data, it seems that in 2nd last record, For Pune city, area and pincode both column has NaN. Do you want to fill both? Same is for Last record.

Comment: I want to use city column as search string and if found in area column and pin is given fill up missing values of area column

Comment: where is the lookup table for Cities? there is no way for a program to know whether Pune is a city or an Area.

Comment: Yes there is no way for that but if area in city column matches the area in area  column then we will get the pincodes for those areas as well, else no. at least we will get few pincodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need.

```
#df.replace('?',np.nan) #use this if you indeed have '?' instead on NaN in the columns & the nuse the line below
df['Pincode']=df.groupby('Area')['Pincode'].fillna(method ='ffill')
```

**Input**

```
      City      Area        Pincode
0   Mumbai      Pune        411009.0
1   Pune        Bandra-E    123456.0
2   Bandra(W)   Badalapur   789456.0
3   Bandra(E)   Bandra-W    258159.0
4   Badlapur    Mumbai      159357.0
5   NaN         Pune        NaN
6   NaN         Bandra-W    NaN
```

**Output**

```
      City      Area        Pincode
0   Mumbai      Pune        411009.0
1   Pune        Bandra-E    123456.0
2   Bandra(W)   Badalapur   789456.0
3   Bandra(E)   Bandra-W    258159.0
4   Badlapur    Mumbai      159357.0
5   NaN         Pune        411009.0
6   NaN         Bandra-W    258159.0
```

Comment: I want to use city column as a search string as I have already filled NaN values using area and pincode column but there is a city for which I dont see any pincodes in pincode column therefore I want to use city column as search string. can we consider Area and pincode as my master table and with the help of these 2 column fill up missing pincodes of city?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide data that conveys your intention? With the data you provided, just with 'Area' we can fill the '?'s

Comment: apologies.  I have updated the question. I also notce that in my data most of the area s not present in area column but they are in present in city column and as result no area in area column hence NaN value so with the help of city column can we fill up NaN values in pincodes?
Thanks